# Access scratch org from login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com

Tags: scratch-org, login, scratch-org-definition-file

Is there a way to change the Instance Url or the Login Url for the scratch org? I want to create a scratch org that can be logged in from a standard login.salesforce.com url instead of domain-specific URL, is this even possible and if yes what changes do I have to make to the scratch org definition file in order to do so? My current behavior is when I create scratch org and generate the password it can only be logged in into using the LoginUrl that is domain specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible. Scratch orgs are always on `test.salesforce.com`, although you may also use the scratch org's Instance URL (My Domain) to initiate login.

> current behavior is when I create scratch org and generate the password it can only be logged in into using the LoginUrl that is domain specific

You should be able to log in at `test.salesforce.com`, but it can take 5-10 minutes for user data to sync.

Comment: Yup, scratch orgs are essentially sandboxes and you can definitely login via test.salesforce.com when a password is created for "User User" or when new users are created.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely resolved my issue so I have marked it as the answer. Can you also please link me to the official Salesforce document that talks about this? I spent a lot of time going through different scratch org-related documentation before putting up my question here. I would be nice to have a link to the official document that says this.

Comment: I am not aware of a single document that lays out how login URLs work, unfortunately.

Comment: I've had it take 30-60 minutes for the login to begin working on test.salesforce.com.